# Replacing user variables in MySQL 8 query

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

I have a query which is generated by a query builder and which relies on the computation of user variables in the query to affect the generation of other outputs from the query. As a trivial example of the query, it might look something like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT a, b, c,
           @d := a * b AS d,
           @e := (SELECT MAX(x) FROM t2 WHERE x > @d) AS e,
           @f := @e * c AS f,
           ...
    FROM t1
    WHERE <column-filtering>
) tt
WHERE <variable-filtering>
```

The database server for this system has recently been upgraded to MySQL8, and this query is now producing a lot of 1287 warnings:

> Setting user variables within expressions is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Consider alternatives: 'SET variable=expression, ...', or 'SELECT expression(s) INTO variables(s)'.

which the client is not happy about.

The query is built this way (rather than implementing it as several queries) to allow the results to be filtered based on the computed values as well as the table columns. As the tables involved can be quite large but the filtered results significantly smaller it is desired to filter the results at the database server to avoid the overhead (and cost) of transferring large result sets to the compute server and filtering there.

I've created a [small fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7c0c061923cc6f9568968b5aa6aee2c1) as a cut-down version (with 14 variables, some have up to ~100) of an actual query with real data. How can I refactor this query to remove the variables?

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT 2 into @a` instead of `@a:=2`?

Comment: You can't do multiple of those in one query with the results being dependent on prior computations. Also, you can only use `SELECT ... INTO` with 1 row of data

Comment: If you're set on changing as little as possible with those inner expressions, you can do as the warning suggests & use `SET` statements -- inside a cursor loop. Otherwise, you might start by picking out the minimal parts of those expressions with true dependencies on other variables, and extracting those computations to the outer `SELECT`.

Comment: This query is broken anyway.  It is assigning and using variables in different expressions -- which even earlier versions of MySQL warned about.

Comment: @GordonLinoff agreed, but it has been working. I'd be interested in your suggestions as to how to refactor it.

Comment: @Noah that could be an interesting idea, although I worry about performance. Could you maybe write it up as an answer?

Comment: How about splitting the query into separate CTE? [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=145a26b007e41346a92614f5accab05b)

Comment: @user14717238 don't spend so much effort on a comment - please post it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

You can also do use aliases by defining them in further levels of subqueries:

```
SELECT a, b, c, d, e, e*c AS f
FROM (
  SELECT a, b, c, d, (SELECT MAX(x) FROM t2 WHERE x > tt.d) AS e
  FROM (
    SELECT a, b, c, a*b AS d
    FROM t1
    WHERE ...
  ) AS tt
) AS tt2
WHERE ...
```

(I did not test that, it's just an example to demonstrate the concept)

Comment: Some of the queries have around 100 variables - is that likely to run into a nesting limit? How do you think performance would be affected by that level of nesting?

Comment: That wasn't clear in your question. There must be a practical limit, but it's not documented. If I were you, I'd consider if you really need to do this in a single query, or if you should query the raw data and do calculations in your application. If the task is too complex to be coded efficiently, take a step back and reexamine your assumptions.

Comment: Part of the rationale behind the question was getting good feedback like this. The reason the calculations are being done on the db server is because of the cost of transferring a lot of data from the db server to the compute server. The "cut-down" demo I posted does have 14 variables, but I've also added a note to the question that there can be up to ~100.

Answer (score 2):

This query can be rewritten by separate CTEs as follows:

```
WITH R1 AS (
    SELECT a, b, c, a * b AS d
    FROM t1
    WHERE <column-filtering>
), R2 AS (
    SELECT *, (SELECT MAX(x) FROM t2 WHERE x > d) AS e
    FROM R1
), R3 AS (
    SELECT *, e * c AS f
    FROM R2
), ..., Rn AS (...)
SELECT * FROM Rn
WHERE <variable-filtering>
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=145a26b007e41346a92614f5accab05b)

Comment: This looks like a good approach, I will have to look into whether I can rewrite the query builder to automatically generate the appropriate CTEs. Otherwise all the input to the query builder will need to be rewritten, which is a mammoth task.

Comment: @Nick, I had similar problems after switching from 5.6 to 8. But I did not use the query builder, and the expressions for calculating dependent statistics were stored in the table as strings. Here is a very simplified [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ebdad1e72785b2c1dd60a46c391dee9d) example, I don't know how useful it can be to you.

Comment: Thanks. The query builder we are using is an in-house product converting from XML files into SQL queries so it's not completely applicable but all input is appreciated.